# Recording Screen on Android 1.6

Tags: 1.6-donut, screencast

I have an old device running Android 1.6. Is there any way that I can record the screen on this device? Most tutorials for doing this rely on having a more up-to-date version of Android.

Answer (score 0):

(In order to comment as opposed to answer one needs 50 reputation points.) Unable to root my device I relied on a digital camera and edited to reduce byte size and to crop image to the screen.   Take pictures in dark to reduce reflections, use a consistent setup to avoid misalignment.  ( Only a few devices on Gingerbreadwill takescreenshots.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes the min requirement is gingerbread. It's not possible on lower versions.